# Membership management software with events

Tags: web-apps, reservation

I'm looking for some web based membership management software for a group that I manage. There are plenty out there, and I've had a look at a few of them. However, I'm struggling to find one that exactly meets my needs and I'm hoping someone here might be able to help.

The group I manage is involved in supporting events, however we are often limited on the number of people we can take along to an event. So that everyone has a chance to attend events, we run our own event allocation system which fairly allocates people to events.

What I'm after, is a membership management system that would let people express an interest in an event, to which we can then invite certain people to attend. I think this should be manageable by any **membership management system that supports a wait list/overflow list on events**, but I can't find one that does. Can anyone recommend one, or any alternative approach?

Ideally I'm looking for a free/open source solution, but we're able to pay a license or a small monthly fee if necessary. We can host any software ourselves.

Comment: Are you running a CMS?  How would such an app integrate into what you have already?

Comment: No, our website is currently a static website. As such, there is no requirement for it to integrate into an existing website, and we envisage doing the selection of people from the wait list manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Crowd Compass](http://www.crowdcompass.com).  Although,  in the long run it may be worth the transition from a static site to a site based on an open source CMS like WordPress or Joomla. There is always a lot of support for these sites and costs are low for specialty development. Additionally, these platforms can be extended to improve many parts of your organization that you didn't think you could and despite the fact that these sites are prejudged as backyard arts and crafts, many big business use these platforms, due to thier flexibility and low cost. If done right that may meet additional need moving forward. But before you jump plan. Hope it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Regpack](http://www.regpacks.com/membership/). The system offers a scheduler as well as waitlist options that you can customize.